# Why does my redirected CORS request fail?

Tags: angularjs, cors

My problem is with a angularjs $http call on my app running at localhost:8080

```
var url "https://api.acme.com/RX/v1/user";
$http.get(url).success(function (data) {
    alert('yay');
$scope.user = data;
});
```

The first request succeeds with the following response recorded by Chrome:

```
Status Code:302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
Location:https://login.acme.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.acme.com%2FRX%2Fv1%2Fuser
```

This results in the browser making a second GET request to the redirect location:

```
https://login.acme.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.acme.com%2FRX%2Fv1%2Fuser
```

This second request fails with the following error reported in Chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.acme.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.acme.com%2FRX%2Fv1%2Fuser. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So I have a CORS request from an origin to a url that allows the request that is being redirected to another url that is also configured to allow the request. But the redirect request is failing. Should I expect this to work?

Note, both api.acme.com and login.acme.com are configured to allow all origins using

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the browser setting the Origin to null when the 302 comes back from the XHR request. As an aside this seems strange to me as surely it would make more sense to make the 302 with the original Origin, not null.

When the Origin null arrived at our server, the apache tomcat CORS implementation there (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter, tomcat 7.0.52) does not return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, even if the server is configured to allow ALL origins. **NB: This behaviour is now fixed in the current version of Tomcat 7.**

The solution was to use a different CORS implementation on the server (http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html). This filter returns Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null and the 302 XHR succeeds.

Although I have found a solution I am still uncertain of two things:

1. why the browser sends Origin null when an XHR results in a redirect
2. whether the tomcat filter or the dzhuvinov software filter is responding correctly to Origin null.

Comment: I am also interested in this and solutions to this on client side.

Comment: But isn't returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null makes your service vulnerable? Anybody can set it's origin to null on the client side

Comment: The service is authorized using another mechanism, it allows any origin given the correct token attached to the request.

Comment: specs say: `If a cross-origin resource redirects to another resource at a new origin, the browser will set the value of the Origin header to null after redirecting. This prevents additional confused deputy attacks, but a cost of making it difficult to transparently move CORS resources that support (cookie-based) credentials and simple requests across domains with 3xx status codes one can with non-CORS resources`
https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/

Comment: You shouldn't allow-origin: null.  [W3C has a whole section about this](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/#avoid-returning-access-control-allow-origin-null) but the bottom line is that it pretty much completely defeats the purpose of Allow-Origin in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

see step 6 of this section(7.1.7): http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#redirect-steps

more discussion could be found here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154967

> Unfortunately the convention of transmitting the string "null" makes it seem like it could be a bug; I thought so myself until I tracked this down :)

Comment: I wonder what is the reasoning behind the switch of source origin to null: "If the request URL origin is not same origin with the original URL origin, **set source origin to a globally unique identifier (becomes "null" when transmitted)**."

Comment: Possibly this comment from "The Web Origin Concept" http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454#section-7.3 is in mind:

> Whenever a user agent issues an HTTP request from a "privacy-sensitive" context, the user agent MUST send the value "null" in the Origin header field."

Comment: @DaleOgilvie Maybe, in my case, user agent from `blah.net` first request `a.example.com` (with Origin header set to be "blah.net"), then redirect to `b.example.com` (with Origin header "null").  Add `null` to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on `b.example.com` works, but insecure :(

Answer (score 0):

if you use LoginRequiredMiddleware, be sure to add the url to LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS in settings.py.